# Increase icon size in hitomis/circlemenu

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-menu, android-icons

I am using [Hitomis/CircleMenu](https://github.com/Hitomis/CircleMenu) for showing social media icons and intent to social media activities on onclick.

Its just the default icon size is way too small and i want to increase the icon size.

My code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

CircleMenu circleMenu = (CircleMenu) findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);

circleMenu.setMainMenu(Color.parseColor("#CDCDCD"), R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
circleMenu.addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#258CFF"), R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#30A400"), R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF4B32"), R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#8A39FF"), R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF6A00"), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

circleMenu.setOnMenuSelectedListener(new OnMenuSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMenuSelected(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Jude.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Jude.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent inten3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Jude.class);
                startActivity(inten3);
                break;
            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings button Clcked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 4:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GPS button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}

);

circleMenu.setOnMenuStatusChangeListener(new OnMenuStatusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMenuOpened() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Menu Opend", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMenuClosed() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Menu Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

);

}
}
```

Comment: Do you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

To increase Icon size you need to use latest the reference of the library (1.0.2)

```
 compile 'com.github.Hitomis:CircleMenu:v1.0.2'
```

and change the width property of the circlemenu﻿

```
 <com.hitomi.cmlibrary.CircleMenu
    android:id="@+id/circle_menu"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you increase the scale X and scale Y size. It seems to increase the whole menu size. Here is the code :

```
<com.hitomi.cmlibrary.CircleMenu
android:id="@+id/circle_menu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
android:scaleX="2.0"
android:scaleY="2.0"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

[Click here to see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtA7m.png)

Comment: I have a question - How do you increase the drawable/mipmap image size in this circle menu?

Comment: Another Question - How do you set text for the sub menus?

Comment: Do you have solution to set text for sub menus?

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.hitomi.cmlibrary.CircleMenu
    android:id="@+id/circle_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleX="1.40"
    android:scaleY="1.40"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>
```

Comment: Hi, I think your answer can be improved by properly formatting it and explaining how and why it works.

Comment: You're right, I haven't adapted yet because I'm a new participant.